# How can I tell who I'm allied with in Crusader Kings II?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I would like to start occupying some provinces in Ireland, but my family has been marrying into Irish families for the last generation. As a result, I am allied with many people that I don't even remember allying with. Is there anywhere I can find a list of my allies?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Diplomatic Relations map mode is probably your best bet.  It's the scroll and quill button to the right of the mini-map.  It shows the provinces controlled by your allies along with those controlled by your vassels and those to which your character has a territorial claim.

The Character Interface also has an Allies tab which will list any allied rulers.  It's the far right-hand button in the row of buttons along the top.

Comment: If you use the map mode method, however, you will likely miss far away allies.

Answer (score 6):

Yes,

Open your character page, at the bottom where you see your family, there are tabs for *vassals* and *allies*.

Listed under the *allies* tab are your your allies, and here is shown if they are 'callable' for war.

- Green implies callable, and will assist you
- Red implies not callable, and will not assist you

**N.B**: 
Although even if you ally is highlighted in green, you may not be able to call them under certain circumstances, such as if you already called them in the last 5 years or they are allied or have a truce with your intended target.